# Visual Studio opens on secondary monitor

Tags: visual-studio

I run Windows 10 and have two monitors as shown on the below screenshot:

[image]

Display 2 is set as my primary monitor, but when I start Visual Studio it always opens on Display 1. The same happens with SQL Server Management Studio, because it is based on VS.

Is there a way to fix this - either in VS settings, or by changing display numbers in Windows?

Comment: Can you try swapping the cables from 1 to 2 and give a try ?

Comment: Already tried :). Makes no difference, windows still assigns the same numbers to monitors.

Answer (score 18):

Make sure VS isn't maximized. Move it to monitor 2. Don't maximize. Close VS. Now it should reopen every time on monitor 2. You can maximize it now if thats your thing. Basically VS will remember what monitor its on as long as its not maximized. A lot of applications work this way.

Comment: Joel thanks, that's what I do. Works until next windows restart. So it's not a major issue, just annoying. Was wondering if I could fix it permanently.

Comment: I am not sure it is valid anymore but in older versions of Windows you could Ctrl-Click the Close button to force the window to save size and location.